# Python -lxml xpath returns empty list

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am reading an xliff file and planning to retrieve specific element. I tried to print all the elements using

```
from lxml import etree
with open('path\to\file\.xliff', 'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as xml_file:
        tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
for element in root.iter():
        print("child", element)
```

The output was

```
child <Element {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment at 0x6b8f9c8>
child <Element {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}source at 0x6b8f908>
```

When I tried to get the specific element (with the help of many posts here) - source tag

```
segment = tree.xpath('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment')
print(segment)
```

it returns an empty list. Can someone tell me how to retrieve it properly.

Input :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0" version="2.0">

   <segment id = 1>
    <source>
      Hello world
     </source>
  </segment>
  <segment id = 2 >
    <source>
       2nd statement
      </source>
     </segment>
 </xliff>
```

I want to get the values of segment and its corresponding source

Comment: `'{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment'` is not an `XPath` expression

Comment: @Andersson: tried tree.findall('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment') - still it returns an empty list

Comment: Share HTML source sample and desired output

Comment: @Andersson: added the source. pls let me know how to get the value of all the segment and source tags.

Comment: @mzjn: okay. Will try that !

Comment: @mzjn: It worked! Thanks! If you could add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: The XML in the question is not well-formed btw (attribute values are not in quotes).

Comment: @mzjn: I also mentioned a while ago in my comment  that .// was working as per your input and I asked you to give it as an answer not as a comment so that i can accept it. I did not mention that it was not working.Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code,

```
tree.xpath('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment')
```

is not accepted by lxml ("lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression"). You need to use `findall()`.

The following works (in the XML sample, the `segment` elements are children of `xliff`):

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.xliff")   # XML in the question; ill-formed attributes corrected
segment = tree.findall('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment')
print(segment)
```

However, the real XML is apparently more complex (`segment` is not a direct child of `xliff`). Then you need to add `.//` to search the whole tree:

```
segment = tree.findall('.//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0}segment')
```